# A question of BRST symmetry of bosonic string theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, brst, ghosts

This question relates to [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74567/how-do-i-show-the-existence-of-a-conserved-ghost-number-with-brst-in-bosonic-str)

I tried to verify Eq. (4.2.7) in Polchinski's string theory book vol I p. 127 but I miserably miss a sign

> $$ \delta_B (b_A F^A) = i \epsilon (S_2 + S_3) \tag{4.2.7} $$

---

Necessary equations:
$$ S_2 =-iB_A F^A (\phi) \tag{4.2.4}$$
$$ S_3 = b_A c^{\alpha} \delta_{\alpha} F^A(\phi) \tag{4.2.5} $$
$$ \delta_B \phi_i = -i \epsilon c^{\alpha} \delta_{\alpha} \phi_i \tag{4.2.6a} $$
$$ \delta_B B_A=0 \tag{4.2.6b} $$
$$ \delta_B b_A = \epsilon  B_A \tag{4.2.6c} $$
$$ \delta_B c^{\alpha} = \frac{i}{2} \epsilon f^{\alpha}_{\beta \gamma} c^{\beta} c^{\gamma} \tag{4.2.6d} $$

---

My attempt to verify Eq (4.2.7), 
$$ \delta_B b_A F^A = (\delta_B b_A) F^A + b_A (\delta_B F^A) $$
$$ =  \epsilon  B_A  F^A + b_A (\partial^i F^A) \delta_B \Phi_i =  \epsilon  B_A  F^A +  b_A (\partial^i F^A) (-i \epsilon c^{\alpha} \delta_{\alpha} \phi_i)  $$
$$ =  \epsilon  B_A  F^A - i  \epsilon  b_A c^{\alpha} \delta_\alpha F^A = i \epsilon  (S_2 - S_3)  $$

Why did I get $-S_3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. $\epsilon$ anticommutes with $b_A$.